# QFileDialog keeps reopening

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I wrote a Qt plugin for [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), and inside it I have a QPushButton `browse_btn` to browse for an output folder. 
I use the `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` function and it all works fine. However if I close the plugin and open it again, then click the pushbutton to add a path, the opened window for choosing the path will re-open after I choose a path or close it. If I close the plugin a open it again the 'choose path' window will reopen 3 time and so on...

The similar problem [is still open here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171395/pyqt-qfiledialog-keeps-on-opening-window-after-clicking-on-cancel-or-ok) and [in comments here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html) and probably [solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840502/qt-folder-browser-opening-more-than-once), but since there is no code provided I cannot apply it to solve my problem.

The exact code is following:

```
self.dlg.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.set_output)

def set_output(self):
    folder_path = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.dlg, u"Pick a folder"))
    if not folder_path:
        return None
```

I think this happens because each time I open-close the plugin the separate connection is created with `self.dlg.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.set_output)`, and it only disconnects after I relaunch QGIS

Comment: You can set a boolean flag to connect it only once or run the QFileDialog only if it hasn't run so far.

Comment: @JLev could you please provide a quick example code? I'm just getting started with Qt

Comment: Why are you connecting the signal every time it is emitted? You just have to connect such a signal somewhere that gets executed once (e.g. the constructor of the widget).

Comment: @Mike could you please provide a short example code?

Comment: @Vasily. Edit your question and show **all** the code of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - Add a boolean flag isConnected to your class (or dlg) and init this flag to false.

Then change your connection line to this

```
if (!self.isConnected):
    self.dlg.browse_btn.clicked.connect(self.set_output)
    self.isConnected = true
```